# Created SVG in javascript but it will not connect to CSS or show up in browsers. Any Solutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working to create SVG elements with javascript, however I can’t get styling to work on it. 
It created the SVG and everything shows up in the HTML, in the browser inspector. The class names show up in the opening tags, in the HTML. However, however it is not applying the CSS styling.

In Chrome they show up in the HTML but the CSS inspector doesn’t recognize them and in Firefox they are recognized by the CSS inspector but the still don’t show up in the browser. They don’t show anything in either browser’s window.

I’ve tried 4 methods of applying classes:

my_SVG.className='my-svg';

my_SVG.classList.add('my-svg');

my_SVG.setAttribute('class','my-svg');

my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null,'class','my-svg');

None of them make a difference. I also created this svg manually and it works just fine, but when I try to create it in javascript it wont style. Is there away around this. Also I noticed most of the documentation for creating SVG elements with javascript with commands like `createElementNS();` is on MDN, so does that have something to with why Firefox at least puts it in the CSS inspector? More importantly does that mean this will be impossible in Chrome?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .my-svg {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    svg path.checkMark {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 7;
      stroke: rgba(102, 204, 102, 1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <svg class="my-svg" width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
      <path class="checkMark" d="M25 37 L35 47 L55 32"></path>  
    </svg> -->
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function createSVG() {
      var contianer = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
      var xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xhtml";
      var my_SVG = document.createElementNS('xlmns', 'svg');
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 90 90");
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "80px");
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "80px");

      //my_SVG.className='my-svg';
      //my_SVG.classList.add('my-svg');
      //my_SVG.setAttribute('class','my-svg');
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'my-svg');

      var checkMark = document.createElementNS('xlmns', 'path');

      //checkMark.className='checkMark';
      //checkMark.classList.add('checkMark');
      //checkMark.setAttribute('class','checkMark');
      checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'checkMark');
      checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', "M25 37 L35 47 L55 32");

      my_SVG.appendChild(checkMark);
      contianer.appendChild(my_SVG);
    }

    createSVG();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xhtml";
var my_SVG = document.createElementNS('xlmns','svg');
                                      ^^^^^^^
```

This is wrong. First arg for that function should be the URI of the namespace you're using. Since you have quotes on there, it's a string, and **NOT** the variable you created on the previous line. That string is therefore interpreted as a relative path on your current site, e.g. `http://example.com/path/to/htmlfile/xlmns`, instead of the w3 DTD.

As well, on a metalevel, you probably should call that `xmlns` (`XML` `N`ame `S`pace), `xlm` is just bass ackwards.

Comment: The first line is still wrong, you need to use the SVG namespace to create SVG elements. That's the html namespace.

Comment: Thanks I've made those corrections but I still have the css problems. 
`var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xhtml";
  var my_SVG = document.createElementNS(xmlns,'svg');`

Answer (score 0):

You would need below changes to your code.

1. Use the svg namespace and not xhtml
2. `createElementNS()` should use the variable (**i.e** it should not be enclosed in quotes).

**Change**

```
var xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var my_SVG = document.createElementNS(xlmns, 'svg');
```

**to**

```
var xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var my_SVG = document.createElementNS(xlmns, 'svg');
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .my-svg {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    svg path.checkMark {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 7;
      stroke: rgba(102, 204, 102, 1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <svg class="my-svg" width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
      <path class="checkMark" d="M25 37 L35 47 L55 32"></path>  
    </svg> -->
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function createSVG() {
      var contianer = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
      var xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      var my_SVG = document.createElementNS(xlmns, 'svg');
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 90 90");
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "80px");
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "80px");

      //my_SVG.className='my-svg';
      //my_SVG.classList.add('my-svg');
      //my_SVG.setAttribute('class','my-svg');
      my_SVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'my-svg');

      var checkMark = document.createElementNS(xlmns, 'path');

      //checkMark.className='checkMark';
      //checkMark.classList.add('checkMark');
      //checkMark.setAttribute('class','checkMark');
      checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'checkMark');
      checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', "M25 37 L35 47 L55 32");

      my_SVG.appendChild(checkMark);
      contianer.appendChild(my_SVG);
    }

    createSVG();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Mike : Happy to help!